# "An error occurred during publish" when using Web Deploy

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, webdeploy

I'm trying to use Web Deploy to publish my ASP.NET Core application to IIS. The server is Windows 10 Pro. I downloaded version 3.6 as [the documentation suggests](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html), and the installer said I had a newer version of Web Deploy already installed.

When I set up a Web Deploy profile in Visual Studio and try to publish using the Publish wizard, I get this error:

> An error occurred during publish. Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

For reference, here are the profile files (autogenerated by Visual Studio):

**Web Deploy.pubxml**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>False</ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://localhost</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework>netcoreapp1.0</PublishFramework>
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>localhost</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>HelloCoreWorld</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>InProc</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName />
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Web Deploy.ps1**

```
[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param($publishProperties=@{}, $packOutput, $pubProfilePath)

# to learn more about this file visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=524327

try{
    if ($publishProperties['ProjectGuid'] -eq $null){
        $publishProperties['ProjectGuid'] = 'e3328cb4-6ad9-49c1-8eff-52590ec622df'
    }

    $publishModulePath = Join-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) 'publish-module.psm1'
    Import-Module $publishModulePath -DisableNameChecking -Force

    # call Publish-AspNet to perform the publish operation
    Publish-AspNet -publishProperties $publishProperties -packOutput $packOutput -pubProfilePath $pubProfilePath
}
catch{
    "An error occurred during publish.`n{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message | Write-Error
}
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: are you using the publish wizard to publish the site

Comment: @lazy Yes, edited.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?